# Fix dependency resolution error. The problem I faced is the duplication of class dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies

```
kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.DirectoryEntriesReader found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilder found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilderImpl found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorImpl found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.LinkFollowing found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathNode found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$bfsIterator$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$dfsIterator$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalkKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathWalkOption found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
```

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Then I figured out that the error is because of duplicate classes in packages in kotlin.collection.jdk8, kotlin.internal.jdk7, kotlin.internal.jdk, kotlin.io.path. And the reason of facing this error is that duplicates are occurring because I have two different versions of the Kotlin standard library (kotlin-stdlib) included in my project: version 1.8.10 and version 1.7.20. Both versions contain some of the same classes,and which is causing the conflict.

Then, I ran in the terminal following code:
./gradlew build --scan

After that I received the report and I found that there is kind of constraint resolution of version.

This is the image of the conflicting duplicated dependencies I found in debugCompileClasspath
[Highlighted part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMrYM.jpg)

And this is the image of the conflicting duplicated dependencies in debugRuntimeClasspath
[Highlighted part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrFEV.jpg)

I think of excluding the 1.7.20 version dependency maybe try to updrade the dependency. But, the issue is I don't know how to do it. So, anyone who knows how to solve this error please give some directions and recommend me the resources in order to solve it. And it would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Have you added any dependency which having multiple implementation like debug and release implementation? If no then can you share you build.gradle dependency code.

Comment: See this change for 1.8 migration -> https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#updated-jvm-compilation-target

Answer (score 0):

Currently this config works perfectly for me:

```
AndroidStudio: Electric Eel, 2022.1.1 patch 2
Gradle: 7.5
Android gradle plugine: 7.4.2
Kotlin: 1.8.10
Androidx core-ktx: 1.9.0

In case of using compose: 
Compose: 1.3.3
Compose-bom: 2023.01.00
Kotlin Compiler Extension Version: 1.4.2
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for you input I looked into And I figured out that there was issue with the jdk version in build.gradle file and in plugin you have to edit that file

Answer (score 0):

The error got solve the issue was with the build.gradle(module) file. As Kotlin launched 1.8.10 version of standard library I needed to migrate things which I did and some files were also migrated to 1.8.10 from 1.7.20. But still some file was in the version of 1.7.20 so I needed to change in this like following:

```
plugins{
     id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
     id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
     id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
  }
```

Now there you can see I had written 1.8.10.